# Join multiple objects in an array using Jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

```
            var IDs  = {};
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                data: { 
                    type: "json",
                     requestUrl: "requestUrl",
                      requestWorkflow: "requestWorkflow",
                      directReply: true

                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ) {
                 console.log(data);
                        IDs= data;
                        
                },
                error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert( "something went wrong, please try again: " + errorThrown );
                },
            }); 

            console.log(IDs[0]);
```

Im trying to join objects in an array by their key. I tried some solutions but couldnt fix it. My array is like ;

> [0:{Ids: "6",Name: "Michael"}] [1:{Ids: "7",Name: "Gerald"}] [2:{Ids:
> "8",Name: "Rose"}] [3:{Ids: "9",Name: "Graice"}]

i need like this

> [0:{"6":"Michael","7":"Gerald","8":"Rose","9":"Graice"}]

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried?

Comment: i have share my code that i'm tried. @MilindAnantwar

Comment: do you have multiple array? @santhiranshan

Comment: yes i have multiple array @JayPatel

Comment: Both of these are not valid array syntax. which format/language is this supposed to be?

Comment: array of object value using JavaScript language. @Shrimp

Comment: these are NOT arrays of objects my friend,supposed you want an array of the above objects it has to be like this --> [{Ids: "6",Name: "Michael"},{Ids: "7",Name: "Gerald"},{Ids: "8",Name: "Rose"},{Ids: "9",Name: "Graice"}]

Comment: Noted thank you @Vaggelis . When i convert into JSON.stringify(data); my data shown as below -> [{Ids: "6",Name: "Michael"},{Ids: "7",Name: "Gerald"},{Ids: "8",Name: "Rose"},{Ids: "9",Name: "Graice"}]. Could be possible to get output like this ?  [{"6":"Michael","7":"Gerald","8":"Rose","9":"Graice"}]

Comment: So do you want a single object out of this array or an array with a single object inside ? Anyway,i posted a solution with both so you choose,feel free to ask if you have questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comment :

```js
const arr = [
  { Ids: "6", Name: "Michael" },
  { Ids: "7", Name: "Gerald" },
  { Ids: "8", Name: "Rose" },
  { Ids: "9", Name: "Graice" }
]

const singleObject = arr.reduce((acc,curr) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [curr.Ids] : curr.Name,
  };
},{})
const singleObjectJson = JSON.stringify([singleObject])
const singleObjectInArray = [singleObject]


console.log(singleObject)
console.log(singleObjectJson)
console.log(singleObjectInArray)
```

You should learn more about Array methods and specifically about [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) i used here.